# Open attachment inside .eml

Tags: ipad, mail.app, attachments

I received a email with an attachment in `.eml` format. I can open this file and read the attached email.

That email also has a `.pdf` attachment in the same email, and the mail app show that it is 300KB.

When I try to open it via mail.app, it shows nothing, so I try to open it via Adobe Acrobat and it show me a popup `this document is empty (0 KB)`

How can I open this `.pdf` file?

Comment: Can you try saving the attachments to your Desktop and opening from there? If you just select the email in Mail there should be a "Save Attachments" option on the File menu.

Comment: I am talking about iOS on iPad, not MacOS on mac, I try to download the attachment `.eml` in file folder and open it but it doesn't work.